# Is this spectrum-shifting operator well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Consider a separable Hilbert space (over $\mathbb{C}$), and let $U(t)$ be a one-parameter group of unitary operators so that
$$
 U(t)=e^{iHt}
\tag{1}
$$
for some densely-defined operator $H$ as in Stone's theorem. Let $A$ be any bounded (everywhere-defined) operator on the Hilbert space, and define
$$
 A(t) = U(t)A U(-t).
\tag{2}
$$
For real numbers $\omega$ and $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$, I want to define
$$
 B := 
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\ 
    \exp(-i\omega t-\epsilon t^2) A(t).
\tag{3}
$$
**Question:** Is $B$ a well-defined operator on the Hilbert space? If not, is it at least densely defined? If the answer is "it depends," then is there a simple necessary-and-sufficient condition on $A$ and $H$ such that $B$ is at least densely defined for all $\omega$ and all $\epsilon>0$?

For whatever it's worth, here's the reason for the words "spectrum-shifting" in the title of the question: At least naively, equation (3) implies  $HB=B(H+\omega)+O(\epsilon)$. In physics jargon, if $H$ is the energy operator, then applying $B$ to an "eigenstate" of $H$ shifts its energy by $\omega$, up to an arbitrarily small term of order $\epsilon$. That's the motive, but I don't know when (3) is actually well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $A$ is bounded, then $\|A(t)\| \le \|A\|$ is bounded for all $t$. So the operator $B$ defines a bounded linear operator for $\epsilon > 0$, and
$$
           \|B\| \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt e^{-\epsilon t^2}\|A\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you. To make sure I understand: If $B=\int dt\ f(t) A(t)$ then $\|B\|\leq \int dt\ \|f(t) A(t)\|$? And that's sufficient to ensure that $B$ is well-defined on the whole Hilbert space, given that the integrand is for each $t$?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Yes. Norm distributes over the integral in this way; and you have uniform bound for $\|A(t)\|$. So the resulting integral is a bounded linear operator.

Comment: I believe that you also need to make sure that the integrand is measurable (in some sense) in order for the integral to be well defined. Here it is, as $t\mapsto U(t)$ is strongly continuous.

Comment: @Mogget : That's correct, $A(t)$ is strongly continuous.